# How can I programatically access the ASP.NET route table from a filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter

Is the route table available from the filters?

I'm inheriting from the AuthorizeAtrribute class. All I'd like to do is examine the route table, and then just call the base class (after making some minor setup adjustments). I could look at the raw url, but I'd rather get the value I need from the route table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out you can instantiate an instance of System.Web.Routing.RouteTable by passing in and HttpContext.